# How to create a nested array based on a plain object

Tags: javascript, recursion, recursive-datastructures

I have an endpoint that outputs data in the following format:

```js
const result = [
  {id: 4, parentId: null, name: 'Fruits & Veggies'},
  {id: 12, parentId: 133, name: 'Sanguinello'},
  {id: 3, parentId: 4, name: 'Fruits'},
  {id: 67, parentId: 98, name: 'Sesame'},
  {id: 23, parentId: 3, name: 'Orange'},
  {id: 7, parentId: null, name: 'Grains'},
  {id: 134, parentId: 7, name: 'Flour'},
  {id: 3512, parentId: 23, name: 'Navel Orange'},
  {id: 98, parentId: null, name: 'Seeds'},
  {id: 4122, parentId: 58, name: 'Lamb'},
  {id: 133, parentId: 23, name: 'Blood Orange'},
];
```

And I need to create a recursive function to get a potentially infinitely nested object that should be formatted as follows:

```js
const infiniteTreeOutput = {
  children: [
    { label: 'Fruits & Veggies', id: 4, children: [
      { label: 'Fruits', id: 3, children: [
        { label: 'Orange', id: 23, children: [
          { label: 'Navel Orange', id: 3512 },
          { label: 'Blood Orange', id: 133, children: [
            { label: 'Sanguinello', id: 12 }
           ]
          }
         ]
        }
       ]
      }
     ]
    },
   { label: 'Grains', id: 7 },
   { label: 'Seeds', id: 98, children: [
      { label: 'Sesame', id: 67 }
     ]
    }
  ]
};
```

So:

- If parentId is null those are on the top level (Fruits & Veggies, Grains, Seeds).
- If a given node does not have children then it shouldn't have that property at all.
- If there's orphaned data (like 'Lamb' here of which we don't have its parent, then we should ignore that object).

I have an awful working function but I would love to know if it would be possible to have a recursive solution.

Comment: please add your function. why a recursive function?

Comment: Do you need the solution to be robust against circular parent-child relationships?

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm trying to translate what I have into this invented foods model. Will try to post it asap.

Comment: @ruud-helderman I don't think so. The only case I need to cover is orphaned items (objects without referenced parent in the response). Like the case of "Lamb" in my example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take a simple single loop approach without recursion, but with an object for keeping all nodes.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 4, parentId: null, name: 'Fruits & Veggies' }, { id: 12, parentId: 133, name: 'Sanguinello' }, { id: 3, parentId: 4, name: 'Fruits' }, { id: 67, parentId: 98, name: 'Sesame' }, { id: 23, parentId: 3, name: 'Orange' }, { id: 7, parentId: null, name: 'Grains' }, { id: 134, parentId: 7, name: 'Flour' }, { id: 3512, parentId: 23, name: 'Navel Orange' }, { id: 98, parentId: null, name: 'Seeds' }, { id: 133, parentId: 23, name: 'Blood Orange' }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(({ id, parentId, name: label }) => {
            Object.assign(t[id] = t[id] || {}, { label, id });
            ((t[parentId] ??= { label: '', id: null, }).children ??= []).push(t[id]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(data, null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: what is the ??= ... is that a typo?

Comment: it wouldn't work with a typo ... ;-) --> [logical nullish assignment `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)

Comment: ah! thanks. i copy / pasted into jsbin and it wasn't recognizing it. weird.

Comment: This is a beautiful algorithm once you see how Nina sees it. Since you are using nullish assignment, you could use `t[id] ??= {}` instead of `t[id] = t[id] || {}`. And `t[parentId] ??= { label: "", id: null }` can be simplified to `t[parentId] ??= {}` since you only return the `children` property of this node. Thanks for sharing :D

Comment: @Thankyou, you are right. the default object is just a cosmetic part to keep `label` and `id` in front of the object and `children` at the end.